# video is not running.I want to get the video using java

Tags: java, video

I had downloaded a .flv video of large size using Orbit downloader which cuts the file into eight parts and then joins them back. After downloading , I have found that the video is not running and stops after some time. I want to extract all the video and save it in another file using java program.Can anyone help me , please ???

Comment: what have you tried so far? Post some code or show us your efforts so far please

Comment: @Stefan I have searched for softwares to repair damaged videos.It failed.The I tried cutting the file to shorter pieces and joining them back using java file operations.That too failed. So I am posting my question...

Comment: So this might be the wrong place to ask this question. Try http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand FLV file format for this. Check out http://www.adobe.com/devnet/f4v.html.

Typically flv file contains header fields and some of those fields specify track length, if the file stops in between , your header fields are not storing the right values.